# Setting a master page's master page programmatically

Tags: asp.net

Is there anyway to set a Master Page's Master Page programmaticly? Would I need to do this on each page? I don't have access to the pre_init event from Master. Hrm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the PreInit function place:

```
this.MasterPageFile = "~/masterPage.master";
```

Yes, you will need to put this on each page.  To get aroud it, have all the pages inherit from a base Page and place put the master page reference there.

Comment: this is the route im going with, so it will look like me.master.masterpagefile

Comment: But this isn't setting the master page's master page, is it?  It's just setting the page's master page.  How do you set the master page's master page?  :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMaster.master";
}
```

[Working with ASP.NET Master Pages Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx)