# How to Set Master Page dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to set different Master Pages for the Same Page depending upon userid (i.e. for one user it must set one master page and for another user it must set another master ). Can we set different Master pages for any page dynamically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a master page's master page programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721814/setting-a-master-pages-master-page-programmatically)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/MyMaster.master";
}
```

**Explanation:** You can attach a master page dynamically to a content page. Because the master page and content page are merged during the initialization stage of page processing, a master page must be assigned before then. Typically, you assign a master page dynamically during the PreInit stage.

Answer (score 6):

Please note this article on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMaster.master";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, by setting the [MasterPageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.masterpagefile.aspx) property of the Page. However, this will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if it is called after the [PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) event. Have a look at the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

> The MasterPageFile property can be set only in the PreInit event; attempting to set the MasterPageFile property after the PreInit event will throw an InvalidOperationException exception. If the MasterPageFile property is not valid, an exception of type HttpException is thrown later in the page life cycle, but no exception is thrown when the property is set in the PreInit event.