# How to set Master Page for a group of pages in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, master-pages

I have 10 pages in my application and 2 master pages. I need to set master page dynamically to the pages. I can set using @page directive or this.MasterPage = "url" . But both these needs to be written in each page.

Any method to set the master page to the first 5 pages as MasterPage1 and other 5 pages as MasterPage2? This is easy of i have huge numbers of pages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930965/how-to-set-master-page-dynamically

Comment: @Senthilkumar I already specified that method in the question. For this, i need to set every page's preinit event. I asking any method to set a group of pages like 5 pages using one master page and other pages for other masterpage with out setting each page.

Answer (score 1):

i got. In web.config we have the option to set master page in Page tag of system.web section.