# Determining Roles VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, roles

So firstly I have no code to show as I'm trying to get my head around how to do this first.

So I have a website that has 3 account pages (Patient, Doctor, Admin) that have 3 different pages for these. There is 3 tables named Patient, Doctor and Admin with account/log in and registered details in them. There is also a field in each of these tables called Role and for Patient table I have the word Patient in the field for each record and the same for Doctor and Admin.

In my login page I need to grab these to determine their login. So if patient is logged in then in the masterpage the patient accountlink will turn visible and so on.

How do i grab all 3 of these roles and determine an if, store in session, and use the session in the masterpage to show whichever link.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: First you create your database structure clearly with roles of the user.

Comment: I have this, I have my database created, I have 3 tables (Patient, Doctor, Admin) each tables has details about each of these user types including login details. I also have a field in each of these tables called Roles. For the Patient table under the role field it says "patient" for each record, for doctor table "doctor" for each record and "admin" for each record in admin table.

Comment: Your maintaining  table separately  for three types of users. then what is the use of roles maintaining in those three tables. anyway check the user name and password from that tables and change master pages of the website based on the user types

Comment: What i want to do is, determine their role, and show a different link on the main master page. Once they click on "View Account" on their link there is a different master page. I thought having the role field in each table will help do this in a statement or something behind the login button.

Comment: what kind of roles are going to use. can you mention some roles of the users

Comment: Patient - is a role - so this directs them to the main homepage and show the patient account link. Doctor - is a role and Admin - is a role - i have 3 different users that access this website but each of their account pages do different things.

Comment: First maintain three types of users in single table because there is a possible for same name for patient,doctor and admin. in this case its difficult to find the type of user is doctor or patient or admin.

Comment: I've really confused myself on how i'm doing this. My log in and register is coded manually (no wizard controls used) so I'm unsure how to get roles working. I was going to add in a datareader behind the login button and somehow code an if statement.

Comment: I have three tables because I needed them for other reasons. Like i have a booking table, that uses a gridview to display all the doctors for the user to select one. I won't be abe to do that if i use one user table

Comment: U can create a field "UserType" in the table. if the user is doctor save the usertype as doctor, if the user is patient save the user type as patient etc. now you can display all the doctors in the gridview where usertype = "doctor"

Comment: Right, if I do it that way , what do i do after? Like behind the login button? I need to do an If statement in the masterpage that will pull the result from the code behind in the login button.

Comment: Behind the login button get the user name and find the user type from the database. based on the user type you can change the master page by using Page_PreInit in asp.net. for more details please go through this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx   OR   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930965/how-to-set-master-page-dynamically

Comment: Does that Page_PreInit work to just show a link? I was going to do this : - If role is Patient then patientaccount.Visible = True etc?

Comment: No page_preinit change the master page before the website page loads. if you want to show a link display the link in anchor tag href.

Comment: Shannen Lyons "Nothing is impossible" so first you start coding and work. Stack overflow members will help you. "Help" means that you tried something and need help with a specific part which is not working,
so please start work and  post your attempts so that we can help you! without doing anything how we will help you??

Comment: Use a `Select Case`. `Select Case role`, where role is that users role which has been assigned to a variable. Then for `Case "patient"` put the code for showing that page.

Comment: I was going to use this example - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx but how do i go around doing this part - Roles.CreateRole("patient")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is have one main table where all the login details go. In this table, have a column called Role and when a new account is made, make it also input into the table, the role of the person. 
If you need the other tables for other things, then use an if else statement to also make the information be input into the table that matches its role. (so that means, info input into two tables). This makes it a lot easier.

Then, on the page where the user is redirected after they log in, this is where you write the code to check for the user's role.

```
sql = "SELECT Role From tablename WHERE username = '"& textbox.text &"'"
```

Search the main table using the username of the user to find the role and then use an if statement to make the specific links show.

```
If sql = Patient then
    <code here>    
Else if sql = Admin then
    <code here>
Else if sql = Doctor then
    <code here>
End if
```